# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (28x28 and 784x256)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I am implementing an Linear autoencoder where I feed images of size `(28,28)` but I am getting `RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (28x28 and 784x256)` error

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        # encoder
        self.enc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=784, out_features=256)
        self.enc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=128)
        self.enc3 = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=64)
        self.enc4 = nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=32)
        self.enc5 = nn.Linear(in_features=32, out_features=16)
        # decoder 
        self.dec1 = nn.Linear(in_features=16, out_features=32)
        self.dec2 = nn.Linear(in_features=32, out_features=64)
        self.dec3 = nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=128)
        self.dec4 = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=256)
        self.dec5 = nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=784)
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.enc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.enc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.enc3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.enc4(x))
        x = F.relu(self.enc5(x))
        x = F.relu(self.dec1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.dec2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.dec3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.dec4(x))
        x = F.relu(self.dec5(x))
        return x
net = Autoencoder()
print(net)
Image = torch.randn(1,1,28,28)
net(Image)
```

I am perfectly giving input size which is `28*28 = 784` but I am still getting shape error didn't understood where I am doing wrong.

Comment: I don't know the library you're using here, but the problem appears to be a mathematical one. Multiplying two matrices of size 28x28 with 784x256 is just not possible (the inner dimensions must match). You should analyze the stack trace to find out what it's trying to do.

Comment: @PMF thanks i am using pytorch here

Comment: I saw that, but as I said, I have no experience with that library. But I know that it tries to tell you that the mathematical operation you're attempting to do is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your code you are giving the neural an input of 784 but you giving it a 28
try to change this line like this

```
self.enc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=28, out_features=256)
self.dec5 = nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=28)
```

Comment: thanks it helped, but my image size is `28,28` so why does the linear layer taking only 28, but why not `28*28` neurons?

Comment: i don't know to be sure but I think you can send it as (28*28,28*28)